# .htaccess Redirect 301 - Nothing Happens

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to 301 redirect a couple old URLs

```
http://www.mysite.com/contact/old-page.php
http://www.mysite.com/contact/another-old-page.php
```

to this one

```
http://www.mysite.com/contact/
```

I'm pretty sure my code is correct, since I have used this on other sites with no problem.  I know redirecting is enabled because the non-www to www redirect works just fine.  But for some reason this one-off redirect doesn't work; nothing happens at all when I visit the old page, as if I didn't do anything.

Here's the complete .htaccess file:

```
#Prevent viewing of htaccess
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>

#Enable symbolic links
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

#Force www version of URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#This is the bit that isn't working
Redirect 301 /contact/old-page.php http://www.mysite.com/contact/
Redirect 301 /contact/another-old-page.php http://www.mysite.com/contact/

#Gzip
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/php text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</ifmodule>

#Caching
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 month"
</ifmodule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your redirects look fine, but one possible conflict is that you're using mod_alias (`Redirect`) and mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) together and the URI passes through both modules and both modules can process them, not independently of each other. And sometimes this causes unexpected results.

Try just using rewrite rules and remove the `Redirect` statements. Try adding these two redirect rules **before** your "force www" rule:

```
RewriteRule ^contact/old-page\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/contact/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^contact/another-old-page\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/contact/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!  Although I still wonder why that exact same file has worked for me without trouble on other sites.  EDIT: And I'll mark this as correct in 4 minutes when the site lets me...